# Highcharts: Display current 'Close' values on a button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

jsfiddle.net/sphprhzu

The button I put below should dynamically show the 'Close' values of the current date i'm on with the cursor. thank you!

exaclly like in yahoo finance , ex : 
https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/%5EDJI# ... IjFkIn0%3D

Answer (score 1):

You can take the point object which is hovered from chart.hoverPoints array. Then hook an event and change value of the button on mouse move.

```
    load: function () {
              var chart = this;
              $('#container').on('mousemove', function () {
                var point = chart.hoverPoints && chart.hoverPoints[0];
                    $('#btn').html(point ? point.close : 'shows close value');
              });
            }
           }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sphprhzu/4/

Comment: Nice. I was trying to do a similar thing using callbacks, but only managed to include point-related hover handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/sphprhzu/6/